# Model_exec fails in subprocess.py

Tags: python, optimization

Dear Dakota and python users,

I am using Windows 8.1, Sandia's Dakota GUI version 6.6 and Python 2.7.14 (as suggested by Dakota - https://dakota.sandia.gov/content/latest-gui-manual ). In the preferences I set the path to Dakota executable and path to python interpreter. The cantilever case from tutorial runs properly - as centered parameter study. The Dakota and python executables are detectable in cmd (as response I get the version of programs).

I would like to run case using T-Axi external code ( http://gtsl.ase.uc.edu/T-AXI/ ). I set simulation model (path to model executable and parameters in input and output files), Dakota study (I set genetic algorithm - coliny_ea, variables as continuous design and continuous state with lower and upper bounds with model response) and analysis driver (I set simulation model and Dakota study - variables and response).

When I try to run Dakota study, I get such problem:

```
Dakota reported: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Dakota_projects\dakota_project2_files\drivers\script_python.py", line 367, in <module>
    model_exec = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(model_exec_args), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] Couldn’t file specified file
```

The input file to Dakota is:

```
interface
    analysis_drivers 'python -m script_python'
        fork
            parameters_file 'params.in'
            results_file 'results.out'
            file_tag
            file_save
    asynchronous
        evaluation_concurrency 4
responses
descriptors 'efficiency'
objective_functions 1
    sense 'max'
    primary_scale_types 'none'
no_gradients
no_hessians
method
coliny_ea
    population_size 10
    fitness_type
        merit_function
    crossover_rate 1
    crossover_type
        two_point
    mutation_rate 1
    seed 11011011
    max_iterations 100
    convergence_tolerance 0.001
    max_function_evaluations 100
    model_pointer 'tcdes'
model
id_model 'tcdes'
single
environment
tabular_data
    tabular_data_file 'tabular_graphics.out'
output_file 'dakota.out'
error_file 'dakota.err'
write_restart 'dakota.rst'
results_output
    results_output_file 'results.out'
variables
    continuous_design 7
        initial_point 0.2047 0.212 11.9452 1.4 3000 1.4 1.2001
        lower_bounds 0 0 1 .5 500 .5 0
        upper_bounds .5 .5 20 5 5000 5 5
        scale_types 'none' 'none' 'none' 'none' 'none' 'none' 'none'
        descriptors 'mach1' 'mach3' 'mass' 'rotor_aspect' 'rpm' 'stator_aspect' 'temperature_rise'
```

In the python script file the line 119 is as follows:

```
model_exec_args = "tcdes APc"
```

In the python script file the line 376 is as follows:

```
model_exec = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(model_exec_args), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

In the error file located in DakotaStudy folder I have this comment:

```
Error: cannot open results file "results.out.1" for evaluation 1
```

In the last lines in the out file located in DakotaStudy folder I have this comments:

```
(Asynchronous job 4 added to queue)

    Blocking synchronize of 4 asynchronous evaluations
    First pass: initiating 4 local asynchronous jobs
    Initiating evaluation 1
    nonblocking fork: python -m script_python params.in.1 results.out.1
    Initiating evaluation 2
    nonblocking fork: python -m script_python params.in.2 results.out.2
    Initiating evaluation 3
    nonblocking fork: python -m script_python params.in.3 results.out.3
    Initiating evaluation 4
    nonblocking fork: python -m script_python params.in.4 results.out.4
    Waiting on completed jobs
```

Do you know how to resolve this problem?

Best regards

Comment: Your best chance probably is asking in dakota-users@software.sandia.gov

Comment: I solved this problem by using not Dakota GUI, but Dakota TUI with modyfing example Analysis Driver to my needs.

Comment: no coincidence for me googling "Sandia Dakota TUI", what are you referring to?

Comment: This is just "Text User Interface" or Command Line version of Dakota.